# Origin of “Beating a dead horse”

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrase-origin

The origin of beating a dead horse.  Was this ever a common practice suitable for a specific purpose?  Is it related to the desire to spur a horse into action?

Comment: "Feeding a fed horse" is a common unneeded situation in stables.

Comment: Carrying water to the ocean.

Comment: "Carrying water to the ocean"/"Peeing in the ocean" is a slightly different idiom.  With the dead horse your action has no effect (other than to rile the ASPCA).  Adding a small amount of water to the ocean technically has an effect, but it's too small to notice.

Comment: @gfrench like tears in the rain

Comment: Of course it is "related to a desire to spur a horse into action". To make a horse go faster, you hit its rump; see e.g. horse racing. Maybe if it's very slow, and you're not a careful owner, and it's centuries before animal cruelty is a thought in anyone's mind, you might hit it hard enough to call it "beating". So by beating a horse, you'd get an effect. But if a horse is dead, you're not going to get it to move by beating it, so there is no point beating it.

Comment: attempting to get blood from a turnip

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the idiom is  the following:

According to *Etymology Online*:

'A ***dead horse*** as a figure for something that has ceased to be useful is from 1630s;

***to  flog a dead horse***

''attempt to revive interest in a worn-out topic" is from 1864.'

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flog:

***flog***

transitive verb

1a: to ***beat*** with or as if with a rod or whip

// The sailors were flogged for attempting a mutiny.

Here's an example from Reverso.context.net:

Anyway, not to ***beat a dead horse***, but just to be super clear, I was looking for the key out front, and I thought maybe it was on the side.

Comment: With advances in bioinformatics and quantum computing, there are new outcomes associated with beating a dead horse.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with quadrupeds, except sometimes effigies.
According to the *Maritime Glossary* the phrase dates to the age of sail, and means: "To waste time doing something that will not succeed. Sailors were generally paid one month’s wages at the start of a voyage so that they could pay off any debts they had run up ashore. Sailors called the first month at sea ‘dead horse’ time, because they were working hard (also called ‘flogging’) for nothing. The end of the first month was celebrated by making an effigy of a horse, parading it around the ship, hauling it up a mast, setting fire to it and throwing it into the sea."

Comment: This alleged origin seems to come from the practice of assigning all phrases and saying to a maritime origin. The Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flogging_a_dead_horse) has this as a possibility, but cursory examination shows it to be unlikely.

Comment: I know about that and even the Dead Horse Shanty ("They say old man your horse is dead") but I still believe that the expression refers to the pointlessness of flogging an expired equine and that the maritime tradition comes from the land based expression.